# I can't access multiple IndexPath rows textfields

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database, custom-cell

I am new to coding and do not understand how to word things properly and how to clean up my code but here goes.

I have a view controller. In the view controller I have a view with a view and a tableview. In the view, I have an UIImage with tap gestures enabled and three textfields. In the nav bar, I have a nav UIButton. When the nav UIButton is tapped the information in the text fields as well as the image is sent to my storage database.

Inside the the table view I have a prototype cell. In the prototype cell I have four text fields. These textfields are constrained by setting a tableviewcell class. That code looks like the following:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ConsiderationsCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var nameTextFieldConsiderations: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var feedTextFieldConsiderations: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var storyTextFieldConsiderations: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var compensationTextFieldConsiderations: UITextField!

override func awakeFromNib() {
super.awakeFromNib()

nameTextFieldConsiderations.placeholder = "Name"
nameTextFieldConsiderations.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
nameTextFieldConsiderations.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
nameTextFieldConsiderations.backgroundColor = UIColor.secondarySystemBackground
nameTextFieldConsiderations.textColor = .label
let nameTFC = nameTextFieldConsiderations.text

feedTextFieldConsiderations.placeholder = "#"
feedTextFieldConsiderations.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
feedTextFieldConsiderations.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
feedTextFieldConsiderations.backgroundColor = UIColor.secondarySystemBackground
feedTextFieldConsiderations.textColor = .label

storyTextFieldConsiderations.placeholder = "#"
storyTextFieldConsiderations.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
storyTextFieldConsiderations.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
storyTextFieldConsiderations.backgroundColor = UIColor.secondarySystemBackground
storyTextFieldConsiderations.textColor = .label

compensationTextFieldConsiderations.placeholder = "$"
compensationTextFieldConsiderations.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
compensationTextFieldConsiderations.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
compensationTextFieldConsiderations.backgroundColor = UIColor.secondarySystemBackground
compensationTextFieldConsiderations.textColor = .label
}



required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
super.init(coder: coder)
 }

}
```

I have a send function right now that is sending data from the first row to my firebase database. The code for that function is the following:

```
 import UIKit
 import Firebase

class ConsiderationsViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var numberOfPeople: [String] = []

var AddPersonCell = "AddPersonCell"

@IBOutlet weak var CompanyImage: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var companyNameTextFieldConsiderations: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var companyDescriptionTextFieldConsiderations: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var startDateTextFieldConsiderations: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var endDateTextFieldConsiderations: UITextField!

let datePickerS = UIDatePicker()
let datePickerE = UIDatePicker()

    var database: Database!
    var storage: Storage!
    var selectedImage: UIImage?
    
    var ref:DatabaseReference?
    var databaseHandle:DatabaseHandle = 0
    
    let dbref = Database.database().reference()
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
        self.companyNameTextFieldConsiderations.delegate = self
        self.companyDescriptionTextFieldConsiderations.delegate = self
        
        // Set the Firebase reference
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ConsiderationsViewController.handleSelectCompanyImageView))
         CompanyImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
         CompanyImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        
        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
        title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        
        createDatePickerForStart()
        
        createDatePickerForEnd()
        
    }

    @objc func handleSelectCompanyImageView() {

        let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        pickerController.delegate = self
        pickerController.allowsEditing = true
        present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
    
  @IBAction func AddPersonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    numberOfPeople.append("#")
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                   self.tableView.reloadData()
                   }
}

   @IBAction func sendButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    
    let companyNameC = companyNameTextFieldConsiderations.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let companyDescriptionC = companyDescriptionTextFieldConsiderations.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    
    let today = Date()
    let formatter1 = DateFormatter()
    formatter1.dateFormat = "MMM d y"
    print(formatter1.string(from: today))
    let todaysDate = formatter1.string(from: today)
            
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "MY STORAGE URL HERE")
    let imageName = companyNameTextFieldConsiderations.text!
    let storageCompanyRef = storageRef.child("Company_Image_Considerations").child("\(todaysDate)").child(imageName)
    let companyDescriptionTextFieldText = companyDescriptionTextFieldConsiderations.text
    let dateToStart = startDateTextFieldConsiderations.text
    let dateToDecide = endDateTextFieldConsiderations.text
    let companyRef = Database.database().reference().child("Considerations").child("\(todaysDate)").child(imageName)
    let index = IndexPath(row: 0,section: 0)
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at:index) as! ConsiderationsCell
    let nameTFC = cell.nameTextFieldConsiderations.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let feedTFC = cell.feedTextFieldConsiderations.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let storyTFC = cell.storyTextFieldConsiderations.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let compensationTFC = cell.compensationTextFieldConsiderations.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    
    let values = ["Feed_Quantity": feedTFC, "Story_Quantity": storyTFC, "Compensation": compensationTFC]
    let considerationInfluencerRef = Database.database().reference().child("Considerations").child("\(todaysDate)").child(imageName).child("Users").child("\(nameTFC)")
    
        guard let imageSelected = self.CompanyImage.image else {
            print ("Avatar is nil")
            return
                }
                   
                var dict: Dictionary<String, Any> = [
                    "Company Image": "",
                    "Company Description": companyDescriptionTextFieldText!,
                    "Start Date": dateToStart!,
                    "Decision Date": dateToDecide! ]
    
                   
        guard let imageData = imageSelected.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) else {
            return
                }
    
                let metadata = StorageMetadata()
                metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"
                storageCompanyRef.putData(imageData, metadata: metadata, completion:
                { (StorageMetadata, error) in
                if (error != nil) {
                return
                    }
                            
                storageCompanyRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                if let metadateImage = url?.absoluteString {
                dict["Company Image"] = metadateImage
                   
                companyRef.updateChildValues(dict, withCompletionBlock:  {
                (error, ref) in
                if error == nil {
                print("Done")
                return
                    }
                  }
                )
               }
             }
                            
                                   storageRef.updateMetadata(metadata) { metadata, error in
                                    if error != nil {
                                    //Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                                    } else {
                                    // Updated metadata for 'images/forest.jpg' is returned
                                }
                            }
                        })

    considerationInfluencerRef.updateChildValues(values as [AnyHashable : Any]) { (error, ref) in
    if error != nil {
    print(error ?? "")
    return
                       }
    
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}


func createDatePickerForStart() {
    // center text in field
    startDateTextFieldConsiderations.textAlignment = .center
    
    // toolbar
    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.sizeToFit()
    
    // barbutton
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: #selector(donePressedStart))
    toolbar.setItems([doneButton], animated: true)
    
    // assign toolbar to textfield
    
    startDateTextFieldConsiderations.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    
    // assign datePicker to text field
    startDateTextFieldConsiderations.inputView = datePickerS
    
    // date picker mode
    datePickerS.datePickerMode = .date
    
}

func createDatePickerForEnd() {
    // center text in field
    endDateTextFieldConsiderations.textAlignment = .center
    
    // toolbar
    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.sizeToFit()
    
    // barbutton
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: #selector(donePressedEnd))
    toolbar.setItems([doneButton], animated: true)
    
    // assign toolbar to textfield
    endDateTextFieldConsiderations.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    
    // assign datePicker to text field
    endDateTextFieldConsiderations.inputView = datePickerE
    
    // date picker mode
    datePickerE.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime
}

@objc func donePressedStart() {
    // formatter
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .medium
    formatter.timeStyle = .none
    
    startDateTextFieldConsiderations.text = formatter.string(from: datePickerS.date)
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

@objc func donePressedEnd() {
    // formatter
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .medium
    formatter.timeStyle = .medium
    
    endDateTextFieldConsiderations.text = formatter.string(from: datePickerE.date)
    self.view.endEditing(true)
     }

   }
    
   extension ConsiderationsViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
               func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
                   //print("did Finish Picking Media")
                   if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey(rawValue: "UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage")] as? UIImage{
                       selectedImage = image
                       CompanyImage.image = image
                   }
                   dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
               }
    }

   extension ConsiderationsViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return numberOfPeople.count
   }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: AddPersonCell, for: indexPath) as! ConsiderationsCell
    
    return cell
   }

}
```

I am able to get the first row text field sent using this function and it looks like the following in my database:

[image: database]

I can send the second row but I have to change the index path to:

```
let index = IndexPath(row: 1,section: 0)
```

I would like to have each row to add the name textfield name under each user node. I would also like the feed, story, and compensation textfields in each row to be under each name textfield node that they correspond to.

If there is a better way to do this I am all years. I have been trying to do this for the last 2 weeks.

(In the future I will need help with the name textfield corresponding to a specific user in my database and be able to show them the company information as well as their specific node information)

Please help!!!

Comment: I want to help since this have been bugging you so long. Not exactly sure where you need the help. Can I see your cellForRowAt indexPath method where you select from your downloadedCompany array and call a function within your custom cell to add the company information?

Comment: I don't have anything like that. I'll edit the code to show the entire view controller.

Comment: Hey Waylan. Were you able to take a peak at my edit?

Comment: Yes but sorry it's hard for me to understand what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to send all the data within each cell to Firebase by selecting a button in your navBar?

Comment: That is correct! I am trying to create a type of form. Each time I send out the form, I would like to be able to add people that see it. Rather than having multiple text boxes created, I would like to use a table in order to add people that I send the above information as well as the information in each row. I may want to send the company information to 5 people. I then would add 5 cells and put the people's name in the name textfield. Each user would then have specific information that only pertains to them. This info is added in the row with their name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to set the labels equal to their corresponding textfields for their correct indexPath.row. Here is the code I ended up using:

```
extension ConsiderationsTestViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    return ConsiderationsTestViewController.people.count
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
return 72
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: AddPersonCell, for: indexPath) as! ConsiderationsCell
    
    let numberOfPeopleCells = ConsiderationsTestViewController.people[indexPath.row]
    
    
    cell.nameLabelC.text = numberOfPeopleCells.Name
    cell.feedLabelC.text = numberOfPeopleCells.PostNumber
    cell.storyLabelC.text = numberOfPeopleCells.StoryNumber
    cell.compensationLabelC.text = numberOfPeopleCells.Compensation
    cell.userImage.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: numberOfPeopleCells.ProfileImageUrl!)
    
    cell.userImage.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    
    cell.nameLabelC.numberOfLines = 0
    
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == .delete) {
        
        ConsiderationsTestViewController.people.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        // handle delete (by removing the data from your array and updating the tableview)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

```
    for index in 0..<numberOfPeople {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ConsiderationsCell
        let nameTFC = cell?. nameTextFieldConsiderations.text!
        //Get all fields
        // Call FB method
    }
```

Comment: Hey Waylan. I posted a new question yesterday. If you could check it out that would be awesome